# Issues when initialising hotjar with Next.js and Typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, hotjar

I'm failing to initialize hotjar in my Next.js and TypeScript app using `react-hotjar version 6.0.0` .

My steps include:

In the file `_app.tsx`

I import it using

```
import { hotjar } from 'react-hotjar';
```

Then I initialize it in the default `function App` as follows:

```
    useEffect(() => {
            hotjar.initialize(HJID, HJSV);
    }, [])
```

Yet when I run

```
next build && next export
```

I receive the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Identifier 'hotjar' has already been declared (11:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| ***
| 
> export const hotjar = ***
|   initialize: function initialize(id, sv) ***
|       hotjar(id, sv);
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/react-hotjar/index.js
> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

Any idea of what can be the reason for the failure?

Alternatively, can you point me to resources describing how to initialize hotjar in the TypeScript Next.js web app?

Comment: I have the same issue. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as well. To address the problem, I had to revert to a previous version. Currently, I'm using V 5.5.0.